# Java. nio. Ошибка при копировании файла

Tags: java, io

У меня есть папка:

```
/Users/pavel/Desktop/test
```

В ней есть папка `sub` `/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/sub/` и файл `root.txt` `/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/root.txt` я пытаюсь скопировать файл `root.txt` в папку `sub`. Что-бы получилось `/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/sub/root.txt`

я делаю так:

```
File source = new File("/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/root.txt");
File dest = new File("/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/sub/root.txt");
dest.createNewFile();
Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
```

у меня валится с ошибкой:

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /Users/pavel/Desktop/test/sub/root.txt
```

Хотя `dest.createNewFile();` я сделал. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл `/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/sub/root.txt` уже существует.

Перед тем как создавать новый файл, проверьте его на существование:

```
if (!dest.exists()) { 
   dest.createNewFile(); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Можно добавить в метод `copy` 3-й параметр - [CopyOption][1].
Есть опция `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`. Если файл существует, то он перетрется.

```
File source = new File("/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/root.txt");
File dest = new File("/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/sub/root.txt");
Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

А вообще, не надо делать `dest.createNewFile()`, можно просто указать куда копировать, и файл автоматически создастся.
[1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/CopyOption.html